# converting values of a matrix of order (NxN) to a vector with order (NxN, 1)

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, data-conversion

I have a matrix let's say A with NxN order (here, 3x3) given by:

```
A = | a b c|
    | d e f|
    | g h i|
```

And I want to convert this matrix into a single vector of order [NxN, 1] (here, 9x1) given by:

```
P = |a|
    |b|
    |.|
    |.|
    |.|
    |i|
```

So, right now what I'm using for converting it for a larger order of matrices & vectors is:

```
% A is a given matrix with some arbitrary values of order (N,M)

P = zeros(N*M, 1);
  
for i = 1:N
    for j = 1:M
       P((i-1)*M + j, 1) = A(i,j)
    end 
end
```

But I am still getting some values in the vector P that is having values as zeros. I'm not sure what am I doing wrong. Any suggestions, what should be the correction in the code?
I also feel there is a possibility that some values are getting overlapped over some already filled data fields in the vector P.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always simply unroll the vector

```
P=A(:);
```

And of course, of you don't like this ordering

```
Aaux=A.'; %transpose first.
P=Aaux(:);
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning what is the order in which MATLAB picks elements from matrices when "unrolling" (and therefore why a transpose in necessary to achieve the desired result given the OP's input).

Comment: @Ander Biguri thanks for the answer, that too was so simple.

Comment: @ Dev-iL, I think that transpose was done to change the order of the elements how it is going to be appended to the vector, like horizontally or vertically. And thanks for pointing out, I will see how I need to use that.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at the `reshape` [function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html).

reshape is really handy for either turning vectors into matrices:

```
>> a = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9]
a =
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
     8
     9
>> M = 3
M =
     3
>> N = 3
N =
     3
>> b = reshape(a,M,N)
b =
     1     4     7
     2     5     8
     3     6     9
```

or turning matrices into vectors!:

```
>> a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
a =
     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
>> b = reshape(a,numel(a),1)
b =
     1
     4
     7
     2
     5
     8
     3
     6
     9
```

if you're making a matrix into a vector, `reshape` is especially powerful when combined with `numel` (documented [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.numel.html?s_tid=doc_ta)).